# C++ Define Array with Const int

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, size, constants

I'm just learning about C++. I'm doing practice with initialize list, so I made a class like this

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
        const int x_size;
        const int y_size;
        int *data;

        Matrix(int _x_size, int _y_size) : x_size(_x_size), y_size(_y_size)
        {
            data = new int[y_size][x_size];
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            delete[][] data;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    Matrix A = Matrix(10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

And compiler said as: array size in operator new must be constant.
So I searched and someone said, these are not 'compiler time constant'.

But it is obvious that I can't use that size as macros in here...
Then. How should I get proper-sized array with Constructor?

Comment: You should really be using a single, 1D array, and add access via two indices. The 1D array could be an `std::vector<int>` to simplify things.

Comment: Forget about arrays, use std::vector.

Comment: The deletion would be `delete[] data;` btw - the `delete[]` form covers arrays of any dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just learning c++ then the best tip is stay away from memory management. Use the stl types if you can. Use a std::vector to replace that array:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
```

create it like this:

```
data(y_size, std::vector<int>(x_size, 0));
```

and access it like this:

```
data[i][j];
```

As jaunchopanza said, you can also use a 1D array which might be better. You would create and edit it in similar ways:

```
std::vector<int> data;
data(y_size * x_size, 0);
data[y_size*i + j];
```

The advantage is that it is faster for accessing, especially if `x_size` and `y_size` are going to be large. There is also an advantage in that the vector of vectors may be stored all over the place, as in each row(or column) will be  in different places in memory. If you intend to get data that overlaps more than one row (or column) then it would be better to use the 1D array for speed.

You can Find more info here: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

If you want to turn this into a matrix and do math etc. Than I would highly recomend `Eigen` it is by far the best matrix library: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Downvoter, care to add a comment explaining so i can make my answer better?

Comment: OP seems to be attempting to get one block of data, which is the right thing to do. A vector of vectors is a bunch of fragmented data blocks. It doesn't seem like the best way to represent a standard N*M matrix.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yep i think you may have just seen that I edited it as well.

Comment: IMHO there's no "best" way to represent a matrix; it depends on what you're going to do with it. A vector of vectors has some advantages and some disadvantages.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree, i mean the vector of vectors is easier to read for one.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out the data layout issue in your answer. It is so easy to make a vector of vectors that inexperienced programmers might start using it without worrying about the drawbacks.

Comment: Ok guys thanks. One more question - why did you think accessing memory directly when I'm not good at Cpp is discouraged? Please let me know-

Comment: @Ben I'd like to see some evidence of the 1D array being faster to access! Also there is the possibility that once the array is large, the vector of vectors is faster to grow new rows.  It seems to me that the main reason to use a vector of vectors here is that it is a lot easier to learn, understand, and use. I'd rather a new programmer use a vector of vectors and then move onto learning other basics, before jumping into the advanced software engineering scenarios of comparing performance differences between these two options.

Comment: @user3811223 `stl` types are built for c++, they are crazy efficient, certainly more efficient than anything you or I could write, they are safe and you are less likely to do silly array things with them. They also provide awesome functionality like iterators and functions like `.size()`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But an N*M matrix has N rows and M columns. It does not grow rows. And it doesn't need to allow for its rows growing or shrinking. And it is quite common to operate on all its elements in as a single block, especially when using 3rd party linear algebra libraries. I think it makes sense to explain all of these things to beginners.

Comment: @juanchopanza The issue about needing to "flatten" it is certainly worth mentioning . As a beginner at C++ it's tough enough to write correct code, let alone have a good mental picture of the pros and cons of each design decision so personally I wouldn't be too prescriptive.

Answer (score -2):

you should write sth like this ( although it is not exception safe)

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
        const int x_size;
        const int y_size;
        int ** data;

        Matrix(int _x_size, int _y_size) : x_size(_x_size), y_size(_y_size)
        {
            data = new int* [y_size];
            for(int i =0 ; i < y_size ; i++)
            {
                data[i] = new int[x_size] ;
            }
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            for(int i= 0 ; i < y_size ; i++)
            {
                delete [] data[i];
            }
            delete[] data;
        }
};
```

Comment: This violates the Rule of Three, and exception-safety; and even if you fix both of those , it is a huge amount of code bloat compared to the one-line option of using a vector of vectors.

Comment: this code is for educational purpose to fix his original idea and yeah it is not exception safe :)

Comment: The fact that this is for educational purposes is exactly why this is a bad answer: We should teach C++ newbbies about resorce management, raii, value semantics, etc; not manual memory management

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't agree with you although using raii and resource management is highly recommended , they are not always available in all compilers and systems i think that the excerpt of code i wrote should be familiar to every c++ programmer